# Can not get Data from resolver in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

my resolve:

[image: my resolve]

my component:

[image: my component]

I haved tried "this.route.data.subscribe" and "this.route.snapshot.data['objectPost']" but i still can get the post's data.
Can someone explain whhat is my problem please...?
Thanks :D

Comment: The code looks fine. Could you check that the post exists in `lstPosts` array?)

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Post it as plaiin text.

Comment: sorry my bad. This is my first time :D

Comment: I found problem was ':postID' return a string and the e.id is an integer, so in order top use '===', I had to use 'e.id.toString()' :D
let p = lstPosts.find(e => e.id.toString() === postID);
Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing through 'paramMap'

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DemoResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor() {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    console.log(route.paramMap.get('postID')); // try with this code
  }
}
```

Note: Check if you have registered your resolver in your module as this example:

```
{
  provide: 'DemoResolver',
  useValue: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => response
}
```

For more information:
https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: I found problem was ':postID' return a string and the e.id is an integer, so in order top use '===', I had to use 'e.id.toString()' :D
let p = lstPosts.find(e => e.id.toString() === postID);
Thanks for your comment

Comment: Glad that you solved it, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to know about resolving is that route will change when resolved data is ready.

So, this is the flow:

1. your route -> `localhost:4200/child2`.
2. resolver takes the action.
3. your route will change to `localhost:4200/child2/:postID`.

So when your resolver takes the action the route still is `localhost:4200/child2` and `route.params.postID` will return `undefined`.

You can use `Location` from `@angular/common` to `replaceState` of url and then navigate to `child2/:postID`. This way you will have id in resolver.

Comment: I found problem was ':postID' return a string and the e.id is an integer, so in order top use '===', I had to use 'e.id.toString()' :D
let p = lstPosts.find(e => e.id.toString() === postID);
Thanks for your comment